# Splitting JQuery Mobile Listview in more rows

Tags: html, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I know I can split up the rows in a Listview vertically by creating blocks like so:

```
<li >
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
        <div class="ui-block-a">Block A</div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">Block B</div>
        <div class="ui-block-c">Block C</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Is there a horizontal way to do this? For example, I have a picture, and I'd like to add two rows next to that. To make things clear, I've added a HD quality example:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have blocks stacked aboved each others, give them 100% `width`.

#### HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="" />
      <div class="ui-grid-b">
        <div class="ui-block-a">Block A</div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">Block B</div>
        <div class="ui-block-c">Block C</div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
.ui-block-a, .ui-block-b, .ui-block-c {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Aw8yt/)**

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="img url" />
        <h2>Home 1</h2>
        <p>A peaceful home</p>
        <p><strong>With large garden</strong></p>      
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Yeah it works. Even though I hoped the JQuery Mobile libary had something 'built-in' like the `ui-block-?`. If you don't mind, I'll leave this question open for a while and if no answer is given, I'll accept yours.

Comment: I don't mind you leaving it open. This is a built in jQM solution as jQM handles the thumbnail graphic automatically putting it on the left, and then places the text rows on the right.

Comment: Actually you are totally right, since using the `<h?>` and `<p>` tags are for that. But I just saw Omar's answer and saving myself the pain of padding pixels, that solution is perfect for me. Thank you for your input!

Comment: No worries. I like Omar's solution too.